# Cannot read PostGIS RASTER into ArcGIS using the interoperability extension, either directly by Query Layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, raster, fme-form

This post [Accessing PostGIS raster data using Query Layer in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30291/accessing-postgis-raster-data-using-query-layer-in-arcgis) was created in Jul-12. Since then, I have not found any other related-post published.

Using QGIS with DBManager ON, my PostGIS raster tables can be displayed nicely so far. That's cool and it proved that my raster tables are OK and not corrupted. However, I need to use ArcMap 10.1 and read those rasters, without having to create views or multi-polygons in the database as the above post suggested.

I have tried two ways:

- Setting a Database connection in ArcCatalog directly to the PostgreSQL/PostGIS database. I can display vector features, but only see the attribute table of the raster, so not displaying the raster as a whole. I guess this has not been implemented so far by Esri, has it?.
- By using the Interoperability extension and its PostGIS file type, I can see my geometries within my database, anything new, so I am able to add those raster tables into my ArcCatalog tree. Interesting, at least this time, the icon of the element instead of being a table icon seems to be a point feature icon, so something different is going on. But when I try to display these point geometries (a kind of cells?), it says "Error reading Interoperability Data. The operation failed because the database table does not have a numeric number".

If I were able to add this numeric number into my raster table at the database - still I don't know how to do it- would I be able to finally visualize the raster?, or would I see just only the table again?. Would version 10.2 of ArcGIS improve this a little?. Is there any other way round to solve this within ArcGIS?

In the other hand, am I having these issues because I have not done something at the database level which I was supposed to do with my raster files? Has someone succeeded at adding PostGIS rasters into ArcGIS?

Comment: In addition, a person belonging to Safe Software company has recently told me that the Data Interoperability Extension (and similarly, FME-extended ArcGIS) do not support rasters currently. I hope this helps. However, still I hope having a solution by setting a direct connection to Postgress/PostGIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Interoperability extension of Safe Software does not support reading rasters from PostgreSQL. And, Esri does not display raster tables from PostgreSQL either.

Problem solved, it is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You can view your PostGIS rasters in QGIS3 as any other raster layers.